# Второй одинковый объект в списке не отражается

Tags: python, массивы, list

Столкнулся с проблемой,что при нахождении определённых символов в array, программа просто игнорирует такой же второй элемент, и в output показывает то,что было в input.

К пример вот мой код:

```py
list = str(input()).split()

dict = {"X-(": "Angry",
        "</3": "Broken Heart",
        ":_(": "Crying",
        ":*)": "Drunk",
        "|-O": "Yawn",
        ";)": "Winking",
        ":-)*": "Kiss",
        ";-)": "Winking",
        ":S": "Sarcastic",
        ":-(": "Sad",
        "XD": "Laughing",
        ":)": "Happy",
        ":-)": "Happy",
        ":-*":"Kiss",
        ":-P": "Frustrated"}

for key,value in dict.items():
    if key in list:
        b = list.index(key)
        list[b] = value
    else:
        pass
print(' '.join(list))
```

В этом коде пользователь вводит текст в виде смайликов, и программа выдёт ему перевеённые в текст смайлики.

**Если ввести такой текст:**
*I like you so much How its going :-P :-P*

**То он выведет:**
*I like you so much How its going Frustrated :-P*

В этом и является проблема,что при виде второго же такого символа в input он его игнорирует и оставляет таким же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
if key in list:
```

на

```
while key in list:
```

И да, не называйте переменные `list`, `dict` и т.п. *(именами встроенных типов/функций)* Сами же рано или поздно на свои же грабли наступите.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще это всё делается гораздо короче (переменные я переобозвал, чтобы не было пересечения с встроенными типами питона):

```
print(' '.join(dict_.get(w, w) for w in list_))
```

Просто перебираете слова и заменяете по словарю. Где не находит слово в словаре - оставляет исходное. Для этого используется второй параметр метода `.get` словаря, там прописывается, что должен выдавать словарь, если нет такого ключа.